# Gnuplot: Skipping points from data file when plotting a matrix

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I have a data file containing a matrix of numbers, that has a form similar to this:

```
nan  nan  nan  nan
0.5  nan  nan  nan
0.1  1.3  nan  nan
3.5  0.1  0.8  nan
```

I would like to plot this matrix, but skip certain points from the plot, let's say the value `1.3`, so that in the plot it appears like as though the value was `nan`.

I've seen posts showing how to skip rows or columns, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215940/gnuplot-how-do-i-skip-columns-in-matrix-input-to-plot), or how to do what I want using heatmaps ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359253/how-do-i-skip-rows-in-gnuplot-when-plotting-a-heat-map)), but this requires a different form for the data files, if I understand it correctly.

Is this also possible using a matrix plot, i.e.,

```
plot "datafile.dat" matrix w image
```

or would i have to reformat my data file?

For a little bit of background; the data files contain the population of states of an atom after interaction with an external field and I'd like to exclude the states initially populated before the interaction from the plot.

Comment: Are you using the data to generate a heat map?   If so then I would approach it differently.  Assign a custom palette that shows the special value using a special color (maybe background color).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify the data with `using` in `matrix` mode also. Columns 1 and 2 will contain indices, and column 3 the value of matrix element. See `help matrix examples`. So you can do:

```
plot "/tmp/f" matrix u 1:2:((abs($3-1.3)<1e-5)?1/0:$3) w image
```

I am not sure why, but column 3 contains a floating point representation of the original data which is not found to be exactly equal to the original input: hence the `abs`.